# GDAL conda install on Mac OS Sierra error

Tags: python-3.x, conda, gdal

I'm trying to install gdal on my new computer in the anaconda environment using conda but having issues. All I've done so far is install Anaconda for python 3.6 and [install gdal as described here](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/gdal) + a few other libraries using both conda and pip.

Trouble is when I try to run from "osgeo import gdal" in the iPython console in spyder I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-3-a04b80bf4e65>", line 1, in <module>
    from osgeo import gdal

  File "/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/osgeo/__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    _gdal = swig_import_helper()

  File "/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/osgeo/__init__.py", line 17, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_gdal', fp, pathname, description)

  File "/anaconda/lib/python3.6/imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)

  File "/anaconda/lib/python3.6/imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)

ImportError: dlopen(/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/osgeo/_gdal.cpython-36m-darwin.so, 2): Library not loaded: @rpath/libicui18n.58.dylib
  Referenced from: /anaconda/lib/libgdal.20.dylib
  Reason: image not found
```

Am I missing a step?